# ¿Cómo Imprimir ñ en C++ usando Codeblock?

Tags: c++

No puedo lograr imprimir la ñ en el mensaje "Estamos en el Año 2019"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

 setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.UTF-8");

    string NAME;

    cout<<"\nEstamos en el Año 2019: "<<endl;
    cout<<"\nIngrese NOMBRE : ";
    getline(cin,NAME,'\n');
    cout<<NAME<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Yo estoy usando

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.UTF-8");
```

Por que es la unica manera de que al ingresar nombres por teclado  con ñ , me los pueda guardar en variable e imprimir.

Comment: ¿En tu sistema tienes configurados los locales como es_ES.UTF-8? Por ir descartando cosas....

Comment: disculpa , donde verifico eso? . Al referirte a Sistema te refieres a ?

Comment: Es que das pocos datos. Especifica sistema operativo y configuración de locales (en casa sistema se hace de forma distinta). Puede que estés pidiendo que tu programa use UTF-8 pero tú lo tengas configurado para es_ES ISO-8859-1 por ejemplo. Por mucho que le digas a tu programa que use UTF-8... si no está en el sistema esa configuración de locales.... dificilmente podrá hacer algo ;-)...

Comment: Te refieres a los Codepages: Uso windows 10 pro x64 , conozco los estandares

Comment: ascii->iso 8859-1->iso 8859-15->windows 1252->utf.8->utf-16 . Lo que ignoro es en que parte de windows puedo verificar cual uso

Answer (score 0):

En base a lo que te comentaba antes, y suponiendo que en tu sistema operativo puedas usar la tecla **ñ** sin problemas supongo que estás usando otra configuración de localización, por ejemplo **ISO-8859-1**.

Prueba a poner

> setlocale(LC_ALL, "ISO-8859-1");

Es posible que así te funcione. Recuerda que existen barias configuraciones locales que configuran la letra ñ.